# How to render only a single cell in MUI datagrid column?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, rendering

I already worked with MUI datagrid and used renderCell to set special functionality for all the cells in a specific column. How can I render only a single cell in a MUI datagrid column?

Comment: You could use the renderCell(params) method as you already did, and check the row parameters (params.row) to render one row for that specific column differently. Let me know if you want me to provide a full working example on this.